# ¿Cómo comprobar la integridad de una base de datos SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Me gustaría saber como hacen los administradores de servidores para comprobar la integridad de las bases de datos SQL cuando tienen miles y hasta millones de usuarios. También sería interesante saber cómo recuperan la información perdida.

Saludos.

Comment: hola, consigue reputación para realizar este tipo de preguntas en el [chat]. Te sugiero revisar [ask].

Comment: @Jorgesys Gracias! Lo tendré en cuenta. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @Morganmariano, tu pregunta se debería dividir en dos preguntas, la primera sobre integridad y la otra sobre recuperar informacion perdida, el desarrollo de ambas serían de gran ayuda para la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

La única forma de comprobar la integridad de datos es mediante las restricciones de clave foranea, este mecanismo se encarga de hacerlo por ti, y genera exepciones cuando no se cumple. En caso de que no exista seguramente tengas datos huerfanos, y esto lo puedes comprobar haciendo consultas de este tipo:

```
SELECT id
FROM hijos
WHERE padre_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM padre);
```

Obviamente si tienes muchos datos y dependiendo de las características del servidor esta query puede tardar mucho en ejecutarse, puedes hacerlo en un Slave que no use producción para evitar problemas.

Como comentamos de Slaves, para que la integridad de datos este bien entre un Master y un Slave, debes asegurarte que no haya retardo (delay) durante el proceso de replicación.